# How to convert display methods into fields in ax2012

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, axapta

**Dear great minds i want to convert this display method into field for PurchLine grid in ax2012  particularly i am facing issue to set condition where to set this condition ?**

```
[SysClientCacheDataMethodAttribute(true)]
display PurchLineShowItemName itemName()
{
    PurchLineShowItemName purchLineShowItemName;

    if (this.ItemId)
    {
        purchLineShowItemName = this.inventTable().itemName(this.inventDim());
    }
    else
    {
        purchLineShowItemName = this.Name;
    }

    return purchLineShowItemName;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you to create a view that will have a purchline as a datasource and 2 columns e.g.: PurchLineRecId and ItemName and the second column will be a computed field. Then you can implement this logic in a view method.

[Walkthrough: Add a Computed Column to a View](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamicsax-2012/developer/walkthrough-add-a-computed-column-to-a-view)

After that you can add this view as form datasourse and join PurchLine by RecId.